# Gridview does not display

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net

The gridview on my page is set up with templat fields in each column so that I can enter information and save it to my database. There is no data that ties directly into the gridview just the ability to add multiple rows at a time to save the data. I had it displayed with empty textboxes and it was working fine and all of a it stopped and now won't show up. Any clues as to what is happening. Code follows...

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvOLIAdj" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="td8"  CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" PageSize="5" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
  <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approval Date ">
        <EditItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server"></asp:Label>              
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtAdjAppr" runat="server" CausesValidation="True"></asp:TextBox>
          <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="txtAdjApprt_MaskedEditExtender" runat="server"   ClearMaskOnLostFocus="False" ClipboardEnabled="False" Mask="99/99/99" TargetControlID="txtAdjAppr" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="125px" />
      </asp:TemplateField> 
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Amount">
        <EditItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"></asp:Label>                                                                            </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtAdjAmt" runat="server" CausesValidation="True"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="225px" />
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comments">
        <EditItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtCmmts" runat="server" Width="599" CausesValidation="True"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField>
        <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="lblInitials" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="35px" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
  <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
  <FooterStyle BackColor="#003399" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
  <HeaderStyle BackColor="#003399" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
  <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
  <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
  <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
  <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
  <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
  <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: A bit strange that your EditItemTemplate contains Labels whereas your ItemTemplate contains TextBoxes ;)

Comment: I guess you have to set some data source for any rows to show up at all? Or at least set some kind of edit mode property? Is any of the sorts done in the code behind? Can you show us the code behind code?

Comment: So you're saying that it has worked fine and without any changes it stopped working overnight?! What is the DataSource of the GridView since you need at least a fake DataSource and DataBind it.

Comment: There isn't any code behind for the gridview, I have an add record button that takes the values and puts it in a database, that is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Potential causes:**

- You are not setting to edit mode, gvOLIAdj.EditIndex = 1;
- CssClass="td8" is set to display:none/visibility:hidden
- gvOLIAdj.Visible=False is
  being set
- You upgraded your framework, see below

[GridView sets EditIndex property when in previous .NET versions it didn't](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/554166/gridview-sets-editindex-property-when-in-previous-net-versions-it-didnt)

Comment: so I was able to get the gridview to appear using gvOLIAdj.datasource = dt gvOLIAdj.databind() but its displaying over 20 blank rows? How do I get just one to display at a time but to add another line automatically when it hits the last edit box?

Answer (score 0):

Gridviews must be bound to a datasource of somesort, the view you see in the designer is only an estimation of what the gridview will look like.